# change t4template to add Long Description

Tags: entity-framework

I use a t4template to create the C# classes for the entities. One thing missing in these generated classes is de documentation that I enter in the Entity Framework designer.

Does anyone know which statement I can use to add the Long Description of a property to the generated code?

Answer (score 0):

The objects representing entities and properties in the T4 template have a Documentation property that exposes this information.  See [System.Data.Metadata.Edm.Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.documentation.aspx).